# np.linalg.det() different result than my calculation

Tags: numpy

I am trying to understand how computing the determinant works.
I have:

```
b = np.array([ [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5 6,7] ])
np.linalg.det(b)
>>> 1.7763568394002396e-15
```

Now, this is how I understood it:

```
>>>>>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
               [2, 3, 4],
               [5, 6, 7]])
>>>>>>> |b| = |1  2  3|   = 1|3  4| - 2|2  4| + 3|2  3|
              |2  3  4|      |6  7|    |5  7|    |5  6|
              |5  6  7|
        |b|               = 1*(3*7 - 4*6) - 2*(2*7 - 4*5) + 3*(2*6 - 3*5)
        |b|               = 1*(   - 3   ) - 2*(    - 6  ) + 3*(    - 3  )    
        |b|               =   (   - 3   ) -   (    - 12 )   + (    - 9  )
        |b|               =       -3               +12             - 9     = 0
```

Haven't I understood it correctly?

Why `det()` is returning `1.77` while I am ending up with `0` ?

Should it be maybe the following instead?

```
>>>>>>> |b| = |1  2  5|   = 1|3  6| - 2|2  6| + 5|2  3|
              |2  3  6|      |4  7|    |3  7|    |3  4|
              |3  4  7|
```

Comment: `1.7763568394002396e-15` seems really close to `float64` machine precision isn't it? Have a look at something like https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: everything is correct: numpy resurns 1.7763568394002396e-15 which is practically zero, not 1.77! You overlooked the e-15.

Comment: @Stef, that I did not know. When you said everything is correct, did you point out to my 1st attempt or the 2nd? because both attempts give me ```0```. Second question please, how did you know that ```1.7763568394002396e-15``` is ```0```? is there a method of some sort which computes such a result?

Comment: Ok, if I ```round(np.linalg.det(b))``` I get a ```0```

Comment: both manual methods are correct and yield the same result

Comment: to get an exact result you can use `sympy.Matrix([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5, 6,7]]).det()`

Comment: @Stef, that was very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the above comments meant is that `numpy` output:

```
b = np.array([ [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7] ], dtype=np.float64)
np.linalg.det(b)
>>> 1.7763568394002396e-15
```

may roughly be seen as `0. +/- roundoff_errors` where `roundoff_errors` are pretty close to `np.finfo(np.float64).eps = 2.22e-16` which corresponds to machine accuracy for `float64` datatype. Indeed, `np.linalg.det` does not compute determinant analytically but relies on a numerical approximation using LU factorization of `b` (as stated in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html)). I don't have looked at the source file to see what `numpy` exactly does but it surely boils down to something like:

```
from scipy.linalg import lu_factor
b_LU = lu_factor(b)

def lu_det(A_LU):

    # The determinant of a permutation matrix is (-1)**n where n is the number of permutations.
    # Recall a permutation matrix is a matrix with a one in each row, and column, and zeros everywhere else.
    # => if the elements of the diagonal are not 1, they will be zero, and then there has been a swap
    nswaps = len(A_LU[1]) - sum(A_LU[1]==np.arange(len(A_LU[1])))
    detP = (-1)**nswaps

    # The determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the elements on the diagonal.
    detL = 1 # The unit diagonal elements of L are not stored.
    detU = np.prod(np.diag(A_LU[0]))
    # Matrix containing U in its upper triangle, and L in its lower triangle.

    # The determinant of a product of matrices is equal to the product of the determinant of the matrices.
    return detP * detL * detU

lu_det(b_LU)
>>> 4.4408920985006196e-17
```

which again is non-zero but quite close indeed! If you want a true zero, you may want to have a look at `sympy` for symbolic calculations, which gives simply:

```
import sympy as sp

sp.Matrix(b).det()
>>> 0
```

Hope it is clearer to you now.

Comment: That is what I call a perfect answer! Yes, it is clearer to me now. Thank you! And thanks to @Stef who pointed that out in the post comments as well.

Comment: Far from perfect but I am glad that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the first principles in numerical methods is that you should never compare two floating-point numbers strickly using `==`. Here you are asking why `1.7763568394002396e-15` is **not equal to** `0.0`. Your question assumes they are "equal", i.e. you are implicitly using `==` in your argument.
You should never compare two floating point numbers (i.e. any numerical value in the context of `numpy`) without a **tolerance value**.

The `1.77` in your question is in fact [image: 1e-14], which
is within tolelance:
[image: eq], using a tolerance value such as [image: eq]
.

Comment: I have neither implicitly nor explicitly mentioned or pointed out how ```1.7763568394002396e-15``` is not equal to ```0```. My question was why I am getting a ```0``` and not what the determinant computation is returning. Other comments pointed out that I missed the point of ```e-15``` which made total sense and you also mentioned that in your comment making it more clear. Thanks for the explanation.